# Erase element from unordered_set of shared pointer

Tags: set, shared-ptr, unordered

Suppose there is a unordered set of shared pointers. I would like to erase the elements from the unordered set with the knowledge of the raw pointer of that element. If I create a dummy shared pointer from that raw pointer and erase that dummy shared pointer, I got double free. How could I fix the bug? Thank you.

```
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iostream>

struct myclass{
    myclass(){ std::cout << "constructor\n";}
    ~myclass(){std::cout << "destructor\n"; }
};


void erase(std::unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<myclass>>& set, myclass* raw_ptr) {
    std::shared_ptr<myclass> dummy{raw_ptr};
    set.erase(dummy);
}


int main() {
    std::unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<myclass>> set;

    std::shared_ptr<myclass> s_ptr{new myclass};
    auto raw_ptr = s_ptr.get();

    erase(set, raw_ptr);
 
    return 0;
}
```

I would expect the output to be:

constructor
destructor